# How do I perform a Clean before Building using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation (MSBuild)

Tags: .net, vb.net, build, msbuild, rebuild

I am using the following code to build a project. I want to perform a Clean first (or just force a ReBuild I suppose?) - but I can't find any documentation stating how I do this:

```
    Private Shared _globalProp As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Private Shared _logger As BuildLogger

    Dim thisProject As Project = Nothing
    Dim buildSuceeded As Boolean

    If _globalProp Is Nothing Then
        _globalProp = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        _globalProp.Add("Configuration", "Release")
        _globalProp.Add("Platform", "x86")
    End If
    _logger = New BuildLogger

    thisProject = New Project(projectFilename, _globalProp, "14.0")
    buildSuceeded = thisProject.Build(_logger)
```

Comment: It looks like you can add an array of build targets (strings) to the Build call. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd234380.aspx

Comment: @JerryM - thanks but I don't know what it is I need to pass in that array. Documentation on this is very scarce

Comment: I'm guessing here. Try adding a statement 'Dim targets As String() = {"clean"}' and then adding targets as the first parameter to the Build call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @JerryM for pointing in the right direction.

I couldn't seem to find an appropriate overload of the Build method that accepted the targets and a logger at the same time, so I am doing this in two steps for now, this seems to do what I want:

```
        thisProject = New Project(projectFilename, _globalProp, "14.0")

        Dim targets As String() = {"Clean"}
        cleanSucceeded = thisProject.Build(targets)

        buildSuceeded = thisProject.Build(_logger)
```

Comment: Perhaps a different version of .Net Framework has the overload that you need. The link in my other comment likes like the overload that you need.